# Unable to send a GET request with a custom header using $fetch() / NUXT / VUE

Tags: vue.js, http, get, fetch, nuxtjs3

```js
async function getArticles(){
    await $fetch(BASE_URL + 'api/article/', {
        headers: {
            "Accept-Language": "TEST IF IT CHANGE",
            "Authorization": "REQUEST_TOKEN"
        },
        method: 'GET',
    }).then( response => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(e => { console.log(e)})
}
```

#### Describe the bug

When we send this request, we can see in the network tab of the browser console that the "Accept-Language" attribute changes. But it is almost impossible to add another header (like "Authorization"). This header (Authorization) is necessary to finish the development of our application.

The header is only modified when modifying the default elements such as: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Connection, Host, ...

For more details see the image.

It should therefore have the possibility to add new entries.

[image]

Comment: Strange, I got that recently with `Cookie`. I assumed that it was a reserved word or alike and that it was legit that it got striped from the call. Maybe you can have a `X-Authorization` or alike?

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-14.8) this is what Authorization header should look like:

`Authorization  = "Authorization" ":" credentials`

If you want to use a different type, try a custom header like `X-Authorization` (like suggested in the comments) for example.

Also, check [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) for examples of different headers.

According to your image (I might be wrong here) if the token is a Bearer, as an alternative, try

```js
headers: {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>'
...
}
```

Or  `'Authorization': 'Basic <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>'`